# How can I convert a tuple to a float in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, tuples

Say I created a tuple like this using a byte array:

```
import struct
a = struct.unpack('f', 'helo')
```

How can I now convert `a` into a float? Any ideas?

Comment: `a` is a 1-tuple with a float value... get the value...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`struct.unpack` always returns a tuple, because you can unpack multiple values, not just one.

A tuple is a sequence, just like a list, or any other kind of sequence. So, you can index it:

```
>>> a = struct.unpack('f', 'helo')
>>> b = a[0]
>>> b
7.316105495173273e+28
```

… or use assignment unpacking:

```
>>> b, = a
>>> b
7.316105495173273e+28
```

… or loop over it:

```
>>> for b in a:
...     print(b)
7.316105495173273e+28
```

And of course you can combine any of those into a single line:

```
>>> b = struct.unpack('f', 'helo')[0]
>>> b, = struct.unpack('f', 'helo')
>>> c = [b*b for b in struct.unpack('f', 'helo')]
```

If this isn't obvious to you, you should read [Lists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [More on Lists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), and [Tuples and Sequences](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could do this:

`a = a[0]`

Comment: It's already a float; that's guaranteed by using the `'f'` format character in `struct.unpack`. So calling `float` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Well, yes, but `a = a[0]` also does it. You might as well write `a = float(a[int(0)]` while you're at it.