# How to convert a tuple to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable with two numbers(decimals). The type of the variable is a tuple. The individual numbers inside are floats. However, I need the type of the variable that combines these two numbers to be a float.

I cannot use the float() as it will only convert 1 item at a time. I tried a for loop, but no luck either.

```
a_1 = 49.1145
b_1 = 50.6547
ab1 = (a_1,b_1)
```

The type of a_1 and b_1 is already a float when I check the type in python.
But the type of ab1 = tuple. I need ab1 to be a float, not a tuple. Any help please?

Comment: what value should `ab1` have? you set it as a tuple..

Comment: what does 'combine' mean? add/store together or what?

Comment: Why would you want the type to be float?

Comment: Either you want `ab1` to be that pair of numbers, _or_ you want it to have a type `float`. A float is not a pair of numbers.

Comment: `ab1` is a `tuple` since it contains multiple `float`s in your case. It cannot be a `float` itself. If you need to check the type of its contents, you could do something similar to `type(ab1[0])` and get `float`.

Comment: I would just need to combine/assign to a variable -  a_1 and b_1 to the variable called ab1. and the values should stil be floats.

Comment: Those values are still floats. The container holding them is a tuple. You can access a_1 by calling `ab1[0]`, and b_1 by calling `ab1[1]`.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "combine" regardless of the programming language. What does it mean to combine two numbers, what operation is that in the mathematical sense? What should `ab1` be equal to after that?

Comment: But I checked now the type(ab1[0]) and I get class 'float' - thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483239/how-can-i-convert-a-tuple-to-a-float-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The `ab1` variable is a tuple and cannot be a float since it contains multiple variables. The variables inside of the tuple `ab1` are in fact floats. You can check this with:

```
type(ab[0])
type(ab[1])
```

If you want to use as a float the variables inside of `ab1` just use `ab1[index]` where `index` is the index of the variable you want to use.

For example:

```
>>> ab1[0]
49.1145
```

Or with calculations:

```
>>> ab1[0] / 2.5
19.6458
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I checked with the index the type and they are indeed floats.